# Simple Javascript animation in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm new to learning React and Gatsby, and am trying to find the best way to apply simple a Javascript animation to a DOM element within a component. I know how to handle component events with onClick etc, but say for example I want to continuously change the colour of a `<span>` in my `Header.js` component every 2 seconds.

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <header>
      <p>This is a <span>test!</span></p>
    </header>
  )
}
```

I'd then want to use some JS like:

```
const spanEl = document.querySelector('header span');
let counter = 0;
const changeColor = () => {
  if (counter % 2 == 0) {
    spanEl.style.color = "red";
  } else {
    spanEl.style.color = "blue";
  }
  counter++;
  if (counter == 10) counter = 0;
}
setInterval(changeColor, 2000);
```

I found that I could put this inside a script tag in `html.js` before the closing body tag, but is there a way to keep this functionality within the component? Do I need to completely rethink my approach when working within this framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to approach this with idiomatic React, then I would recommend expressing this behavior using hooks, component lifecycles, and effects.

The official React docs for hooks and effects are very good, I would start there.

```
import React from 'react';

const noop = () => null;

// Encapsulate the interval behavior
const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
    const savedCallback = useRef(noop);

    useEffect(() => {
        savedCallback.current = callback;
        savedCallback.current();
    }, [callback]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const id = setInterval(savedCallback.current, delay);

        return () => clearInterval(id);
    }, [delay]);
};

export default function Header() {
    const [color, setColor] = useState("blue");

    // setColor causes a re-render of the component
    const updateColor = setColor(color === "blue" ? "red" : "blue");

    useInterval(updateColor, 2000);

    // Use the jsx to change the color instead of reaching into the dom
  return (
    <header>
      <p>This is a <span style={{ color }}>test!</span></p>
    </header>
  )
}
```

Comment: Expanding on your answer, in a real-world case where the animation could be within a bigger and more complex component it might be worth considering creating a separate component for the animated text, in order to re-render only that one when the colour changes.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Strictly speaking these examples are not animations but just scheduled component updates. If you need a real animation then you will have to use React's animation api.

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT: I've just seen the answer from @windowsill, which I think is better than mine; I would recommend going with that solution.]

In a React functional component, you need to use the `useReference` hook to target an element (rather than selecting it with `document.querySelector()`) and the `useEffecet` hook to set and clear the timeout when the component mounts/unmounts:

```
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useCallback
} from 'react';

export function Header() {
  const animatedText = useRef(null);

  const runAnimation = useCallback(elem => {
    const currColour = elem.style.color;
    elem.style.color = (currColour === 'red' && 'blue') || 'red';
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const animationInterval = setInterval(() => {
      runAnimation(animatedText.current);
    }, 2000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(animationInterval);
    }
  }, [runAnimation]);

  return (
    <header>
      <p>This is a <span ref={animatedText}>test!</span></p>
    </header>
  );
}
```

The `useCallback` hook is used for optimization purposes and prevent the function `runAnimation` from being re-defined and initialized every time the component re-renders.